# How to coin a symbol "dddagger"?

Tags: symbols

I would like to combine dagger and ddagger vertically, but the result is not so good just by using the command `\stackbin{ddagger}{\dagger}`, could anybody help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

By using ''newcommand'' you can define your own commands and use the `\ooalign` and `\mathrel` in conjunction you can attain what you want. Note that when using the `\ooalign` environment make sure to use the `$$` environment to define your math symbols.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\newcommand\newdagger{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\dagger$\cr\hidewidth$\ddagger$\hidewidth\cr}}}
\begin{document}
This is the original dagger: $\dagger$\\
This is the original double-ended dagger: $\ddagger$\\
This is the new dagger: $\newdagger$
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Alternatively, you can also try using `\vbox` to get what you need with adjustable vertical spacing as follows:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\newcommand{\newdagger}{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    \hfil##\hfil\cr
    $\dagger$\cr
    %\noalign{\kern0ex}
    $\ddagger$\cr
}}}}
\begin{document}
This is the original dagger: $\dagger$\\
This is the original double-ended dagger: $\ddagger$\\
This is the new dagger: $\newdagger$
\end{document}
```

However, note that here `\kern0ex` is the spacing variable, use negative/positive spacing in the place of `0` to vary the vertical spacing between symbols (to make it how you want it be). An example of the output is shown here which is obtained with `0ex`

[image]

Comment: `\mathbin` should be used instead of `\mathrel` I think. The LaTeX symbol list lists the original `\dagger` and `\ddagger` as binary operators.

Comment: @Troy I am not sure either, anyway thanks for the information, I shall check into this as well :)