# Tripple dagger ⹋ in pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, unicode

Does any package provide the Unicode character [U+2E4B “⹋” (Triple Dagger)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2E4B) for pdflatex? There was an attempt made here: [How to coin a symbol "dddagger"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370680/), but it is not what I am looking for. [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) doesn't seem to know it either.

Comment: pdflatex is not designed to handle Unicode. If you want to use Unicode, then it is advisable to use xe/lualatex. Noto Sans seems to have this particular character. If it is absolutely impossible to switch engine, then another possibility is to compile a separate pdf for just this one character and embed it every time. If that is something you would like to do let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could build their own.  However the shift value of `-.6\ht0` will be font dependent.  Nonetheless, for a given font, I can make it work across size changes.

Here I present two versions: `\DDDag` that is the same width as `\ddag`, but the aspect is not the same; and `\dddag` which retains the proper aspect of the dagger, but at the cost of reduced width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\dddag{%
  \sbox0{\ddag}\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{-.6\ht0}{\ddag}{\ddag}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{\ddag}%
}
\newcommand\DDDag{%
  \sbox0{\ddag}\stretchrel*{%
  \stackengine{-.6\ht0}{\ddag}{\ddag}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{\ddag}%
}
\begin{document}
\dag \ddag \DDDag \dddag

\tiny
tiny: \dag \ddag \DDDag \dddag

\end{document}
```

[image]

For example of a different font, here is palatino, with the shift factor of `.7`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,palatino}
\newcommand\dddag{%
  \sbox0{\ddag}\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{-.7\ht0}{\ddag}{\ddag}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{\ddag}%
}
\newcommand\DDDag{%
  \sbox0{\ddag}\stretchrel*{%
  \stackengine{-.7\ht0}{\ddag}{\ddag}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{\ddag}%
}
\begin{document}
\dag \ddag \DDDag \dddag

\tiny
tiny: \dag \ddag \DDDag \dddag

\end{document}
```

[image]